# Markov and Faithfullness Condition in disconnected DAG/Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian-network, dag, d-separation

I'm very confused about the Markov- and the faithfulness condition in disconnected DAGs, as I've never seen such examples.

Assume for example I had a DAG where X -> Y, Z. Thus, Z is disconnected from X and Y. Furthermore I know that $I_p$({Y},{Z}|{X}) in the Probability distribution.

How do I check if the Markov condition and the faithfulness condition hold in this case?

For the Markov condition, I know that $I_p$({node},$ND_x$|$PA_x$) has to hold.
Here, $I_p$({Y},{Z}|{X}) -> Markov condition holds, because this is also true in the probability distribution.
But looking at Z: $I_p$({Z},{Y, X}) therefore: $I_p$({Z},{Y}) -> Markov condtion does not hold. How can that be?

Faithfulness condition: Does not hold, if the Markov condition doesn't hold in the first place.

Furthermore, (according to Lemma 2.4 of Neapolitan) X and Z are adjacent in G if and only if they are not d-separated by some set in G. Here, X and Z are clearly not adjacent. But they are also not d-separated?

Thank you for your help in my confusion!